# How to fix Header on ListView while using addHeaderView() method in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, header

I am making contact list using JSON and inside this i used a ListView. Inside that i want to add a header & i make it using addHeaderView() method here is the xml and code i had used.

header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Contacts"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

in MainActivity.java

```
    ListView list= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    BaseAdap adp= new BaseAdap(getApplicationContext(),contact_list);


    LayoutInflater inf= (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v= inf.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    list.addHeaderView(v);

    list.setAdapter(adp);
```

By doing this, header is attached to the listview bt it is scrollable when i scroll the list down. Can anyone tell me the method to make this header fixed on top. So that it didn't scroll when i scroll listview down.
Thank in advance, Please Help

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me the method to make this header fixed on top.

Get rid of `addHeaderView()`, and put the header and the `ListView` inside a vertical `LinearLayout`.

Comment: i know this but i have to add header using addHeaderView() method, thats compulsory.

Comment: @SahilGarg: Then the header will scroll with its contents, as that is how `addHeaderView()` works.

Comment: but their must be some way out to do that.